# Single value data to multiple values of data in database relation

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have such a hard time picturing this. I just don't have the brain to do it.

I have a table called `reports`.

```
---------------------------------------------
| report_id   | set_of_bads | field1 | field2 |
---------------------------------------------
| 123         | set1        | qwe    | qwe    |
---------------------------------------------
| 321         | 123112      | ewq    | ewq    |
---------------------------------------------
```

I have another table called `bads`. This table contains a list of bad data.

```
-------------------------------------
| bad_id    | set_it_belongs_to | field2 | field3  |
-------------------------------------
| 1         | set1              | qwe    | qwe     |
-------------------------------------
| 2         | set1              | qee    | tte     |
-------------------------------------
| 3         | set1              | q44w   | 3qwe    |
-------------------------------------
| 4         | 234               | qoow   | 3qwe    |
-------------------------------------
```

I want to setup a primary key to foreign key relationship. My question is, how do I connect the field `set_of_bads` to `set_it_belongs_to` in the `bads` table. This way if I want to get the entire set of data that is `set1` by calling on the `reports` table I can do it.

Example: *hey reports table.. bring up the row that has the `report_id` `123`. Okay thank you.. Now get all the rows from `bads` that has the `set_of_bads` value from the row with the `report_id` `123`, in `set_it_belongs_to` field. Thanks.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one,

```
SELECT  a.*,      -- will display all records from reports table
        b.*       -- will display all records from bads table
FROM    reports a
        INNER JOIN bads b
            ON a.set_of_bads = b.set_it_belongs_to
WHERE   a.report_ID = 123
```

**Update 1**

In your `CREATE TABLE` statement, specify a foreign key constraint on `bads` table

```
CREATE TABLE bads
(
bad_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT   ,
 set_it_belongs_to VARCHAR(50),
 field2 VARCHAR(50),
 field3 VARCHAR(50),
 CONSTRAINT bads_pk PRIMARY KEY (bad_id),
 CONSTRAINT bads_fk FOREIGN KEY (set_it_belongs_to) 
    REFERENCES reports(set_of_bads)
);
```

and make sure that the `primary key` of `reports` table is `set_of_bads`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion John, also thanks for fixing that table format in my post. It made it look better. I actually just edited my post so there is a little more to it. I am actually trying to just setup a foreign key relationship.

Comment: @SofianeMerah then you need to specify a constraint. look at my updated answer :D

Comment: Thanks. Now would `set_of_bads` need to be a Primary Key in the `reports` table? Because I woul like to keep the primary key as `reports_id`.

Comment: Infortuantely yes. You can still be able to have unique keys on report_id if you specify a unique constraint to report_id. By definition, foreign key is the primary key from the other table.